# Редактирование таблиц excel, чтобы загрузить ее в Jupyter Notebook

Tags: excel

Всем добрый день. У меня есть эксель таблица, где каждое значение в своей клетке. Мне нужен формат csv, но чтобы все что в каждой строке (построчно) через разделитель оказалось в одной клетке. Сохранить в csv это понятно, а как через разделитель в одной клетке сделать, не понятно. Помогите плз.

[image: Вопрос на фото, для понимания]

Comment: Мне, например, тоже непонятно, что Вы рассказали. Не получается словами - хотя бы примером покажите...

Comment: ))))) Сейчас, 5 сек)))@Akina

Comment: @Akina готово))

Comment: Ну так при фиксированном количестве столбцов это вульгарный СЦЕПИТЬ(). Или просто Сохранить как - CSV (если нужен текстовый файл на выходе, а нет XLS(X)).

Comment: @Akina спасибо вам, помогло)